# Maven not working in command line

Tags: maven, cmd

hello I can't seem to get mvn command working in command line

These are system variables

I have my path set as C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
and my Maven_Home set as 
C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9

Comment: Only set bin folder into PATH as you did. Open command line and try `mvn --version`?

Comment: [How to install Maven on Windows](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

You should put maven in some location without any space in path. Except that everything looks fine. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724226/why-shouldnt-i-put-spaces-in-my-maven-path-in-windows)