# Maven install Hadoop from source, looking in the wrong path for tools.jar

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am trying to build hadoop-2.4.0-src, using 'mvn clean install'.  About half of it completes successfully, but then the HDFS projetc fails with:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Missing tools.jar at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes/classes.jar. Expression: file.exists()`

`....../Home/Classes/` does not exist, and tools.jar is in `......../Home/lib`.  My `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable is definitely set correctly, and the JDK listed in the error message is correct - it's just looking in the wrong place within that path.  I have seen some postings that a common problem is that people are using the JRE and not the JDK, but I am certain that mine is the JDK.

I have tried both suggestions from the accepted answer here:
[Buiding Hadoop with Eclipse / Maven - Missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118070/buiding-hadoop-with-eclipse-maven-missing-artifact-jdk-toolsjdk-toolsjar1)

...with no success.  Adding the 'dependency' block to Hadoop's pom.xml had no effect, and for the second suggestion I changed the relevant version numbers from 1.6 to 1.7.  I have also tried various other suggestions from similar questions without success.

`which` returns what I expect:

```
$ which javac
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
```

However, the contents of JavaVM.framework/Versions seems strange to me, as it does not appear to list 1.7:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions $ ls -al
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 May 10 11:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel  408 May 10 11:05 ../
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 May 10 11:05 1.4@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 May 10 11:05 1.4.2@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 May 10 11:05 1.5@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 May 10 11:05 1.5.0@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 May 10 11:05 1.6@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 May 10 11:05 1.6.0@ -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 May 10 11:05 A/
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 May 10 11:05 Current@ -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 May 10 11:05 CurrentJDK@ -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

I am relatively new to Java, so I'm having trouble figuring out where the root of the problem is - is it my local directory tree, as shown by the odd contents of `Versions`?  Is Java not configured correctly (although I have been using Java 1.7 in Eclipse for weeks now with no issues)?  Or is it an issue with Hadoop's pom.xml I need to update somehow?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ran the following to solve the issue on my mac:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/ 
sudo mkdir Classes 
cd Classes/ 
sudo ln -s ../jre/lib/rt.jar classes.jar
```

Ref: 
http://ilovemylinux.blogspot.com/2013/05/maven-jspc-compile-error-with-java-7-on.html